# Securely exchanging public dsa keys for manual use in python

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, diffie-hellman, man-in-the-middle

In a project of mine I am working towards secure TCP communications between a client and a server across an insecure network. Initially I was thinking about just passing this off to openssl, but I've concluded that (because of reasons beyond the scope of this question), I would prefer to deal with the DSA keys manually. While that part is simple enough, there is one remaining problem: How would I send the public key the server while making sure there's no MITM intercepting this key and replacing it with its own?

I have been looking into Diffie-Hellman key exchange algorithm, but I haven't found a way of implementing this in my code without reinventing the wheel, and I am struggling with finding an existing library for it, so I have decided to step back a bit and simply ask:

Is there a library or some other method that allows me to exchange keys securely, while allowing me to apply the keys manually? Basically, I want to do the actual encryption/decryption with keys myself, but I need a reliable way of exchanging the public keys involved.

Using python 3.6.9 on linux. I have access to openssl and the usual linux-tools.

Comment: First of all, library recommendations are off-topic, unfortunately. Secondly, you say you can't use openssl, but you also say you don't want to reinvent the wheel. That's a contradiction. Finally, Diffie-Hellman (DH) alone is completely vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks. Why do you think DH is a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Diffie-Hellmen algorithm should be easy to implement, the simple example on Wikipedia highlights all the steps that are programmatically easy to execute.

[image]

Comment: True, but when we're talking about 4096bit DH, I am pretty sure there is a better way of doing it than writing it from scratch, as I doubt that I'm the first one needing to do this and therefore presumably there are more efficient methods out there than whatever I can conjure.

Comment: are you sure you want to use synchronous key cryptography? asynch methods are safer and easier

Comment: I'm only using the synchronous cryptography for the initial step of exchanging DSA public keys. I gave pyDH a look earlier, but I find that the documentation is severely lacking. Also, I'm not set on DH alone, as I am also curious about alternatives.

Comment: i was mistaken in my previous comments, its symmetric and not synchronous. and DH is a asymmetric approach for a symmetric system

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question as I understand it.